# PRESTASHOP - additional configuration page

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a custom prestashop module and i need to add more configuration page.

For the time being i can configure it on only a single page by using the getContent() function,
how to add more pages.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `tabs`.

You can get content for your tabs in the `getContent()` function from other functions in your module. You can use `FormHelper` for both forms.

Let's assume you have `settings` form and `statuses` form. You can do something like this:

```
public function getContent()
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'settingsHtml' => $this->renderSettingsForm(),
        'statusesHtml' => $this->renderStatusesForm()
    ));

    $configurationForm = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');
    $this->html .= $configurationForm;

    return $this->html;
}
```

And then in your `configure.tpl` file you can do like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="settings"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Settings' mod='yourmodulename'}</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="statuses"><a href="#statuses" aria-controls="statuses" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Statuses' mod='yourmodulename'}</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
        {$settingsHtml}
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="statuses">
        {$statusesHtml}
    </div>
</div>
```